# Component binding not working

Tags: angular

I have an `address` component, a `combinedAddress` component, and a component that calls these.  For some reason the model binding is not getting into the `address` component.

Current debugging HTML in outer component - street displays a prepopulated value of `123`:

```
Entity: {{application.entity.physicalAddress.street}}
<combinedAddress-component [(physicalAddress)]="application.entity.physicalAddress" [(mailingAddress)]="application.entity.mailingAddress" ></combinedAddress-component>
<address-component name="something" [(address)]="application.entity.physicalAddress" Title="Something"></address-component>
```

HTML for `combinedAddress` - street displays prepopulated value of `123`:

```
<div>
    CombinedAddress: {{physicalAddress.street}}, {{mailingAddress.street}}
    <div>
        <address-component name="physicalAddress" [(address)]='physicalAddress' Title="Physical Address"></address-component>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="isMailingAddressRequired()">
        <address-component name="mailingAddress" [(address)]="mailingAddress" Title="Mailing Address"></address-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML for `address` component - Title displays, but the address line displays nothing.  If you type in the address textbox, the address updates.

```
<div class="well">
    <fieldset>
        Address: {{address.street}}
        <legend>{{Title}}</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input name="address" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="address.street" required placeholder="Address" #address="ngModel" />
            <div *ngIf="address.dirty && !address.valid" class="error">*    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input name="city" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="address.city" placeholder="City" #city="ngModel" />
            <div *ngIf="city.dirty && !city.valid" class="error">*</div>
        </div>

        <state-select [(selectedState)]="address.state" Title="State"></state-select>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
            <input name="zip" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="address.zip" placeholder="Zip Code" #zip="ngModel" />
            <div *ngIf="zip.dirty && !zip.valid" class="error">*</div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And the TS for the `address` component

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Address } from '../../models/Address';
import { StateComponent } from './states.component';
let $ = require('../../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');

@Component({
    selector: 'address-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/reusables/address.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/form/reusables/composite.component.css'],
    directives: [StateComponent]
})
export class AddressComponent{
    @Input()
    Title: String;

    @Input()
    address: Address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coworker helped me find it.  The `address` property in the `.ts` file was conflicting with the `address` name in the `.html` file, so it was looking at the wrong thing.